# How to filter an array of objects based on DateTime to return the earliest object from each month

Tags: powershell

I have an array of objects in Powershell; each object has a property that has a DateTime value (lets call it DateCreated).

```
DateCreated | Name | SomeOther...
____________|______|_____________
2023/05/01  | One  | SomeProperty
_________________________________
2023/05/03  | Two  | SomeProperty
_________________________________
2023/06/02  |Three | SomeProperty
_________________________________
2023/06/07  | Four | SomeProperty
```

I need to filter this list so that at the end I have an array of objects comprised of the earliest object from each month

```
DateCreated | Name | SomeOther...
____________|______|_____________
2023/05/01  | One  | SomeProperty
_________________________________
2023/06/02  |Three | SomeProperty
```

I've thought about writing something that would split out the DateTime column into it's constituent parts, ordering by month and day and getting rid of anything but the first record for each month, but that sounds over-engineered. I haven't written any code as yet that would do what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group the entries by the month/year component of the date, then use [the `Sort-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) to sort the entries in each group one by one to obtain the oldest one.

The easiest way to derive a grouping key from a `DateTime` value is to convert it to a big-endian string format, like `year-month` and then let alphabetical sorting take care of the rest:

```
$oldestPerMonth = $objects |Group-Object { $_.DateCreated.ToString('yyyyMM') } |ForEach-Object {
    # default sort direction is ascending, so simply pick the first item after sorting and you'll get the oldest
    $_.Group |Sort-Object DateCreated |Select-Object -First 1
}
```